# Reducing viewer download bandwidth for very large models

Tags: autodesk-viewer

We would like to use the Autodesk Forge model viewer to display a very large building model.  In most use cases, only a portion of the model will need to be displayed in the browser (defined by a bounding voxel that the viewer will be aware of).  It will not be feasible to have every user wait to download the entire model to the viewer due to the amount of bandwidth that will require and the delay in waiting for the entire model to load.

I am aware that there are ways that we could reduce the size of the published model by filtering the elements that are published, reducing the level of detail/textures, or dividing the model into little pieces.  **This question is about optimizing model load performance for viewing a portion of a single, large model either through the API, by "cooking" the source Revit model element structure prior to publishing, or by manipulating the node structure of the published model.**

What are the recommended techniques for reducing the download size / improving load times when loading a portion of a model?

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware, the RVT file is uploaded to the Forge server for translation to the streamable formats. I am not aware of any access to that process, or options to control it. Therefore, you will either have to pre- or post-process. Post-processing is probably complex, since the streamable translation result format is undocumented. The only pre-processing path I can currently envisage consists in splitting the model up into separate RVT files, or simplifying the entire model and saving that as a minified RVT file, just as you describe.

Comment: The Viewer can load multiple models into the same scene (see Viewer3D.loadModel() method). Perhaps he could split the large model into multiple, smaller models, translate them all, and then additively load each model as needed into the viewer?

Comment: @StephenPreston Is there any technique using the API such as downloading the model structure/index and applying a filter before the model is rendered?  Breaking the model into many small pieces means a more complicated publishing process and then management of all the pieces when viewing.

Comment: Not at the moment - no. We're working on improvements for handling very large models (LOD etc). We'll obviously announce any enhancements when they go live.